# Can I use UsePartitioner in the endpoint configuration in mass transit to partition multiple message types that are delivered to the same queue

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using masstransit and rabbitmq. My queue has messages of various types delivered to it. Most of these types implement IHaveOrganisationKey. I would like to add a partitioner to the pipeline to ensure that only one message (of any type) with a given organisationkey is processed at the same time. The goal is to limit concurrency problems that occur when multiple messages of the same organisation are processed in parallel, while allowing parallel processing of messages from different organisations.

Configuration code

```
sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, this.queueConfiguration.QueueName, ep =>
{
    ep.PrefetchCount = this.busConfiguration.PrefetchCount;
    this.queueConfiguration.ConfigureEndpoint(ep);
    this.queueConfiguration.SubscribeMessages(worker, ep);
});
```

In the QueueConfiguration:

```
public override void ConfigureEndpoint(IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator ep)
{
    // This is incomplete. Am I on the right track here?
    ep.UsePartitioner(1, x => x.TryGetMessage<IHaveOrganisationKey>());
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, you need to create the partitioner separately, and then pass it to each of the message type configurations.

```
var p = ep.CreatePartitioner(8);

ep.Consumer<ConsumerA>(x => x.Message<A>(m => m.UsePartitioner(p, c => c.Message.OrgKey)));
ep.Consumer<ConsumerB>(x => x.Message<B>(m => m.UsePartitioner(p, c => c.Message.OrgKey)));
```

If your consumer has multiple message types, you can specify multiple `Message` statements in the configuration.

Comment: Cheers, Chris! At first I assumed that the partitionCount parameter passed to CreatePartitioner refrered to the number of messages per partition. I now understand that this acts as a global concurrency limit, and that the number of messages for a single partition is always one.